# Audacity, settings revert when opening exported wav

Tags: audacity

I looked through 3 past years of "Audacity" questions here and this hasn't come up.

I have a wav file encoded at a Rate of 22050 bps and a Sample Format of 32 bit float.

I do the following:
1) Change the "Set Rate" setting to 44100 Hz.
This makes the pitch go up an octave.
2) Go to Effect/Change Speed, and apply a multiplier of 0.5
This brings the pitch back to the original pitch.
3) Change the "Set Sample Format" to 16-bit PCM.
4) Export to a new file name, using WAV, 16 bit PCM as the format.

Close Audacity.
Go to the newly made file and open it. 
The settings of this new file show a reversion to the original file: and are listed as Rate of 22050 bps and a Sample Format of 32 bit float.

Why doesn't the new file reflect the settings changes I made?

I've also tried Track/Resample and set the resampling to 44100, then exported the cue to 16-bit PCM wav. Even then, opening the new file (with its own name different from the original) shows a reversion to the 22050 rate.

Any idea what might be going on or what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Audacity 2.1.1 on Windows 10 PC.

Answer (score 2):

What I have found out so far:

1) Audacity prefers to work with 32-bit floats. Even if you save your file as 16-bit, when it comes into Audacity's work area, the calcs are done at 32.

2) There is a Toolbar called the "Selection Toolbar". On it is a control "Project Rate(Hz)". Set the value here prior to export and the setting will stick, unlike the rate drop down from the control area on the left of the sound file.

I couldn't get very good explanations. But using the "Selection Toolbar" is allowing me to make the desired conversions, so I guess I should be satisfied.